# How to insert a picture into the splash screen?

Tags: python, tkinter

I just want to know how could I insert a picture into the splash screen?

```
from tkinter import *


#splash screen

class SplashScreen(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, width=0.8, height=0.6, useFactor=True):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

        # get screen width and height

        ws = self.master.winfo_screenwidth()
        hs = self.master.winfo_screenheight()
        w = (useFactor and ws * width) or width
        h = (useFactor and ws * height) or height
        # calculate position x, y
        x = (ws / 2) - (w / 2)
        y = (hs / 2) - (h / 2)
        self.master.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
        self.master.overrideredirect(True)
        self.lift()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    sp = SplashScreen(root)
    sp.config(bg="#3632ff")


    m = Label(sp, text="MH60 NAVIGATION APP")
    m.pack(side=TOP, expand=YES)
    m.config(bg="#3366ff", justify=CENTER, font=("calibri", 29))

    Button(sp, text="PRESS TO START", bg='red', command=root.destroy).pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Adding images is fairly well documented. Have you read any documentation or looked for examples before asking the question?

Answer (score 1):

Just add some widget with an image to your `SplashScreen` instance. For example, say your splash screen image was this `.gif`:

[image: splash.gif image]

Then adding it to your code would look something like this (via a `Button` widget):

```
from tkinter import *

class SplashScreen(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, width=0.8, height=0.6, useFactor=True):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

        # Add widget with the splash screen image on it.
        self.img = PhotoImage(file='splash.gif')
        btn = Button(self, image=self.img)
        btn.pack(expand=YES, ipadx=10, ipady=10)

        # get screen width and height
        ws = self.master.winfo_screenwidth()
        hs = self.master.winfo_screenheight()
        w = (useFactor and ws * width) or width
        h = (useFactor and ws * height) or height

        # calculate position x, y
        x = (ws / 2) - (w / 2)
        y = (hs / 2) - (h / 2)
        self.master.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
        self.master.overrideredirect(True)

        self.lift()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    sp = SplashScreen(root)
    sp.config(bg="#3632ff")

    m = Label(sp, text="MH60 NAVIGATION APP")
    m.pack(side=TOP, expand=YES)
    m.config(bg="#3366ff", justify=CENTER, font=("calibri", 29))

    Button(sp, text="PRESS TO START", bg='red', command=root.destroy).pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
    root.mainloop()
```

This is how it looks running on my system:

[image: screenshot with splash screen displayed]

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:- Import Module.

Step 2:- Create splash screen.

step 3:- Set title and geometry for splash screen.

step 4:- Insert photo file name to be display.

step 5:- Create Label and Pack the Label.

```
# Import Module
from tkinter import *

splash = Tk()
splash.title("Welcome")                 # assigning title for splash screen
splash.geometry("800x750+300+100")      # set geometry for splash screen
splash.after(4000, splash.destroy)      # splash screen will destroy after 4 sec 
bg = PhotoImage(file = "file_name.png") # insert file name to be display
lab = Label(splash, image = bg)         # create label
lab.pack()                              # pack the label

splash.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your are answering a very old question. Please state in your answer how this improves on the previous answers. Also, please  do not use several answers, just edit the first one if you want to add extra information.

Answer (score 0):

```
bg = PhotoImage(file = "file_name.png") # insert file name to be display
```

1. file_name(photo) should be present(save) in folder where above code is saved.
2. If file_name is not given in code or the image does not exist in folder where above code is saved then the error will appear while running code.

Error:-

_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "file_name.png": no such file or directory

Comment: See my other comment, please add this information in your other answer and delete this one.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are trying to use jpg or other type of file, like jpeg..., check this or change the type of file to png.